# Not able to transform data in expected format in snowflake

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, lateral

I got data in rows for a column like this

```
[
  {
    "value": "A",
    "path": "nth-child(1)"
  },
  {
    "value": "K",
    "path": "nth-child(2)"
  },
  {
    "value": "C",
    "path": "nth-child(3)"
  }
]
```

Need help .....
Want to get  data    like this format in rows from  that column

```
   {
     "A",
     "K",
     "C",   
  },
```

Have tried like  this :  *but it combine all the  rows of the table*

```
SELECT LISTAGG(f.value:value::STRING, ',') AS col
FROM tablename
,LATERAL FLATTEN(input => parse_json(column_name)) f
```

Comment: Please clarify what you need. It appears that you're saying the values need to be one set per row based on the row they came from in the JSON. If that's the case, you can group by SEQ, which is an auto-generated column in the FLATTEN function.

Comment: Did you tried adding 'group by seq', if that is something you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a CTE just to provide fake data for the example:

```
WITH data(json) as (
    select parse_json(column1) from values
    ('[{"value":"A","path":"nth-child(1)"},{"value":"K","path":"nth-child(2)"},{"value":"C","path":"nth-child(3)"}]'),
    ('[{"value":"B","path":"nth-child(1)"},{"value":"L","path":"nth-child(2)"},{"value":"D","path":"nth-child(3)"}]'),
    ('[{"value":"C","path":"nth-child(1)"},{"value":"M","path":"nth-child(2)"},{"value":"E","path":"nth-child(3)"}]')
)
SELECT LISTAGG(f.value:value::text,',') as l1
from data as d
   ,table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f
group by f.seq
order by f.seq;
```

gives:

| L1 |
| --- |
| A,K,C |
| B,L,D |
| C,M,E |

Thus with some string concatenation via `||`

```
SELECT '{' || LISTAGG('"' ||f.value:value::text|| '"' , ',') || '}' as l1
from data as d
   ,table(flatten(input=>d.json)) f
group by f.seq
order by f.seq;
```

gives:

| L1 |
| --- |
| {"A","K","C"} |
| {"B","L","D"} |
| {"C","M","E"} |

Comment: worked, but    Same expression how to use "group by" with other columns ?

Comment: @user19131919 not really sure what you mean by that. Ask a new question with same data of “i have this but what it like this” form.